# MySQL dump works on mysql repo but broken in ubuntu repo

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, mysql

My colleague gave me a mysql.sql.xz in 80mb.

Exported from MySQL 5.6.26

I setup MySQL 5.6.28 in ubuntu 14.04, it only imports partial and broken, syntax error, as I m not able to unzip the files, so i only guess it reads partial SQL, where SQL not correctly ended.

I tried MariaDB 10 and it has the same problem.

I do unxz and only get part of the SQL file, and the last SQL in the file is incomplete.

I tried mysql.com and installed MySQL 5.6.29. It successfully dump in the .xz file.

Can anyone points out what possible problem here?

I have re-install quite many times now, the only working result is get the repo from mysql.com

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If the file is truncated then that is the cause of your problem, right? It really sounds like you have an issue in transferring the file rather than any thing incorrect at either database instance

Comment: imagine the exact same file.xz works for MySQL.com v5.6.29; but failed by ubuntu.mysql.v5.6.28 or mariadb10 or unxz